# Where is the Spell Checker in the Content Editor Web Part in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, content-editor-web-part

Has the Spell Checker been removed from the CEWP in 2010?

In 2007 users using the Rich Text option could spell check content. In 2010, the ribbon is showing no option to spell check. It does however show for publishing pages!

Is the publishing feature required in order to spell check the CEWP? If so, how ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

Spell checking is done using the SpellCheck.asmx web service using functionality implemented in Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing. So it's only enabled when publishing is enabled.

So you need to activate the site collection feature `SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure` then you can use spell check also in CEWP

Comment: I find this shocking, and a step backwards!
Not being able to spell check a "content editor" web part seems daft! This web part is used a lot on non publishing sites. 
Do I want to change up a collaboration site enabling all publishing functionality in order to get spell checking working. Not a chance! It introduces so much that doesn't make sense! Thanks MS.
Rant over, and thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work to enable the spellcheck:

1. Activate the SharePoint Publishing feature at the subsite level.
2. On the SharePoint list, edit both the ‘(Item) Edit Form’ and the '(Item) New Form' from the Form Web Parts (found in the ribbon, dropdown options) and add a ‘blank’ Content Editor Webpart to each of these pages. Set the chrome on each CEWP to ‘None’ so that is does not show on the page for the form. Stop editing the page to save your changes.
3. Test from the form UI. The spellcheck will only work on Enhanced Rich Text fields, however, if you click on an Enhanced Rich Text field first then go back to a Rich Text field, the spellcheck appears to stay active.
4. If this works for you, come back to this site to vote on my suggestion.